# Questions that ask to "do my work for me"

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, off-topic

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847202/how-to-use-curl-to-find-subdomains-containing-specific-strings) 3 days ago. The asker is looking for a way to get all the `CityId`s in a site called `ghix.com`.  Maybe he wants to crawl it. It's okay to crawl it. But I don't think the main question (find city ids) does not relate to any of the tags (php, html, string, loops, curl). Even this site doesn't provide any API. If it was we could have analyzed and answer it. The question is not related to any programming at all.

My question is are these type of questions allowed at Stackoverflow?

Comment: I edited the title; feel free to roll back if you don't like it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's clearly programming related,  but you're right: It's what we on Meta call a [`send-teh-codez`](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/plz-email-me-teh-codez.aspx) question, with no specific, techincal issue in it - just a "my code doesn't work, what do I do?"

I'd say it's fair to close it as "not a real question" or "too localized".

However, as [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847202/how-to-use-curl-to-find-subdomains-containing-specific-strings/8847745#8847745) shows, it's also possible to answer the question without doing the OP's work for them, which is also cool IMO.

Comment: Nice suggestion!